# How do I read a file for a specific line

Tags: c#, io, console-application

I'm making a console application and I need to be able to write, search and delete entries from within text files, I can write files into a notepad file but that's basically it, this is what I have to read the file:

```
public static void SearchDetails()
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter ID Number");

string myfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\file.txt");
System.Console.WriteLine(myfile);
}
```

This brings up all the text in the file but I need to be able to search for a specific number within the file and then brings up the next three lines below it. How to I get it to read the input so that it matches with a number in the text file and then bring up the next 3 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you question and comments to answer, the final answer would be:

```
    public static void SearchDetails()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter ID Number");
    int Id = 0;
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Id);
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\file.txt");
            List<string> IdLines = lines.Where((x, i) => i % 4 == 0).ToList();
            int IdLine = IdLines.IndexOf(Id);
            if (IdLine != -1)
            { //then result found
                //Id is what user searched for or
               // string Id = lines[IdLine*4];
                //string[] results = lines.Where((x, i) => i > IdLine * 4 && i < IdLine * 4 + 4).ToArray();
           for(int i=IdLine*4;i<IdLine*4+4;i++)
            System.Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no results!");
            } 

    }
```

Comment: of course you should handle errors before reading lines as the number entered may exceed the number of lines

Comment: @Ved if the answer worked for you please accept it as answer

Comment: I tried them and I'm not sure how I can get the number searched from the program to be read. How would I specify the number within the [linenumber]?

Comment: Thanks for replying, that definitely got me closer to what I need to do, the main thing I'm struggling though is being able to find a match for the number searched, for example searching 2 will bring up the ID 2 as well as the 3 lines below not just the line number, any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Ved what do you mean by three lines below? you mean all lines 0, 1, 2? I didn't get what you meant

Comment: So within the console program I want to be able to search for a ID number which is located within a text file, when the ID number has been searched the number should show up in the console as well as the three lines below the ID within the text file.
The text file is laid out so each line is on a separate line
Line 1 - ID
Line 2 
Line 3
Line 4 - Another ID

Comment: @Ved have a look at new answer

Comment: I've tried to use your example but I keep coming across an error, "cannot convert from int to string", why is it doing this?

Comment: I've fixed the error by adding ToString but whatever has been searched the program says 'no results'.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do whatever you want with the results but something like this is what you want

```
// Read the file and display next three lines
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\file.txt");

string line;
int lineCnt = 3;
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains(myID) & !bGet) 
    {
        bool bGet = true;
    }

    if (bGet && lineCnt > 0) 
    {
        bool bGet = true;
        Console.WriteLine (line);
        lineCnt--;
    }

    if(lineCnt == 0) {break;}

}
file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```